# C# Determine whether X509Certificate2 Private Key is exportable (redux)

Tags: c#, windows, certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I am having the devil of a time determining whether a X509Certificate2 certificate's Private Key is exportable. According to the research I have done I am supposed to use **CspKeyContainerInfo**. This is what I have so far (removing error checking for brevity). Assume RSA certificate thumbprint *does* exist and that it *does* have a Private Key.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = Cryptography.GetCertificateFromStore(thumbprint);
RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
Debug.WriteLine("RSA Certificate Gettting Exportable status");
// next line generates exception "Key does not exist"
bool isexportable = provider.CspKeyContainerInfo.Exportable;
Debug.WriteLine("RSA Certificate Exportable="+isexportable.ToString());
```

Comment: 2nd line: `cert.PublicKey.Key` -- are you sure you are looking for a public key?

Comment: It's not clear which key you're after. If it's the public one: `CspKeyContainerInfo cpsKey = (CspKeyContainerInfo)((RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key).CspKeyContainerInfo; if (cpsKey.Accessible) { Console.WriteLine("Exportable: {0}", cpsKey.Exportable); }`. If it's the private: `if (cert.HasPrivateKey) { RSA rsaKey = (RSA)cert.GetRSAPrivateKey(); }`. Adapt it to what you're actually looking for.

Comment: What's your scenario?  Note that there are keys that will only open under CNG, and this approach also leaves out ECDSA, DSA, and ECDH keys.  Ultimately, the best way to know is to try to export as a PFX when `cert.HasPrivateKey` is true.  It either succeeds, or doesn't.